# How to access fill color property of an SVG, created with GSAP

Tags: javascript, object, svg, getelementbyid, gsap

HTML code:

```
<div class="dots" id="dotsSlider">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="30" viewBox="0 0 400 60" id="ante">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    // targeting the svg itself
    const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

    // variable for the namespace 
    var svg = document.querySelector("svg");

    var x = i.toString();
    var name = "newCircle" + x;
    var name2 = name;
    var counter = i + 1;
    var position = 36 * counter;

    // make a simple rectangle
    var name = document.createElementNS(svgns, "circle");

    // set attributes of new circle
    gsap.set(name, {attr: {
      cx: position, 
      cy: 25, 
      r: 8, 
      width: 30, 
      height: 30, 
      fill: "black",
      id: name2
    }});

    // append the new rectangle to the svg
    svg.appendChild(name);
```

}

So far so good I created 10 SVGs (dots for a slider). For loop is written inside a function that runs when the page loads. My problem is that I do not know how to access the fill property of these SVGs in order to be able to change it in a dynamic way inside another function. I tried everything related to getElement parsing it to a variable, but propably I am writing something wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var circle = document.getElementById("newCircle3");  // etc
circle.style.fill = "red";
```

Comment: I unfortunately have tried that already. It returns null when I consolelog it

Comment: I can only access the HTML selection of svg#ante with const element = document.getElementById("ante"); -the id of my svg in html- where it shows them as array of objects -among many other things- but I dont know how to proceed

Comment: Okay. Then please update your question with a functioning example - preferably a StackOverflow snippet - so we can see that for ourselves.